# How to check like I am trying to hit url threw apps or browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending request jQuery page to java page like this

```
var url = siteurl + "impression/get?t=" + Math.random() + parameter;"
```

in parameter I have add many fields here related to client device and client OS. Now I want to add one more parameter in request like if I am hitting the URL form browser then it parameter value 1 and if I am hitting the URL from mobile then parameter value is 0.

How can I check this like I am hitting URL form browser or apps ?

Comment: How about checking the user agent? Of course this could be faked but the parameter could as well be faked so there is no real security there.

Comment: yes by user agent I fetching the user device information but I am hitting same thing there mobile browser and mobile app then ?

Comment: I would suggest you to pass an argument in query string..

Comment: yes but argument should be based on like this is coming from apps or web

Comment: Let's try to tackle this in another way: what do you need that for? What apps are you talking about? Do you have any influence on the way they call the url?